# Type mismatch on assigning DateValue

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my code:

```
Dim LFile As Date
LFile = DateValue("Jun 19, 2000")
```

It throws "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Comment: Try datevalue("2000/06/19")  the date format isn't recognized would be my guess. Remember, though, that your computer's system date setting may cause the results of a DATEVALUE function to vary from this example. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

Comment: This is working for me on a US/English Locale.

Comment: Do `MsgBox TypeName(DateValue("Jun 19, 2000"))` and see what it says.

Comment: Works here in UK/English also. I'd suggest this is being caused by `Jun` not matching the 6th month's name in whatever locale is being used.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5(v=vs.90).aspx - The recognition of the string depends on system locale settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all agree above, the DateValue function on your particular system with it's current Locale setting is not recognising `"Jun 19, 2000"` as a valid date.

To check what it *might* recognise, enter `Msgbox Format(36696,"mmm dd, yyyy")` into the immediate window. Either `"mmm dd, yyyy"` is simply not considered valid with that Locale (in which case it will likely not display a date correctly), or perhaps the `Jun` part is not a valid 3 character representation of month 6 in that language (in which case it should tell you what 3 chars you should use for the 6th month).

For better compatibility, DateValue("2000-06-19") should be recognised by (I imagine) all Locale set-ups.